# How to install iis service by using aws cloudformaion template

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, aws-cloudformation

Basically I want to install iis service and its futures and roles by using aws cloudformation template, can some one help ?

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a PowerShell script in the User Data field. The script will be automatically run the **first time** the instance is started.

It would be something like:

```
"UserData" : {
    "Fn::Base64" : {
        "Fn::Join" : [
            "",
            [
                "<powershell>\n",
                "# Install IIS and Web Management Tools.\n",
                "Import-Module ServerManager\n",
                "install-windowsfeatures web-server, web-webserver\n",
                "install-windowsfeature web-mgmt-tools\n",
                "</powershell>\n"
            ]
        ]
    }
}
```

I just copied this from a template I had, so please test it yourself! This example is in JSON format, but you can also use YAML.